# Swipe screen using AndEngine in Android Game

Tags: android, andengine

I'm new to AndEngine. I'm making a game,where I want to implement level selection.
Where I want to use swipe for all levels.
I know about swipe detection. But I don't know how can I implement swipe effect, like scenes are changing. I searched on internet a lot, but couldn't fine useful solution. 
Do I have to make all sprite on one scene or make different scenes?
Any suggestion how to implement this?

Comment: If you post some example then it will become easy for us to understand what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different scenes and at runtime change t scene using

mEngine.setScene(myOtherScene);